# OpenCL vectorization on adjacent workitems

Tags: opencl, gpu

Assume I have an OpenCL kernel where each workitem do one int_32 operation, and my GPU supports 256 bits SIMD operation, will OpenCL be able to pack 8 workitems together to take the advantage of SIMD? i.e. one processing unit do multiple workitems simultaneously. If so, then when will this happen? At "clBuildProgram" stage, or when the binary is actually executed on the GPU (JIT compilation)?

The second one seems more reasonable because this can only be decided after I define the workgroup size, for example, if I say 1 workitem per workgroup, then the vectorization cannot happen?

I looked at the Nvidia ptx file after "clBuildProgram" and I still saw scalar IR, but I'm not sure about Intel or AMD.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, if the GPU is going to perform SIMD instructions on your data, it'll decide that when your code is compiled (whether by an online compiler, or by an offline compiler). It's probably not going to decide that based on how/when you define your workgroups.

As for whether your data will be vectorized or not... That's a bit more complicated.

It depends on how exactly you've laid out your data and the logic of your kernel, as well as how much the (presumably online) compiler chooses to optimize your code. It ALSO depends heavily on the actual hardware, but I'll talk about that in a moment.

- Vector data types (like `float4`, `int4`, `float8`, etc.) are the easiest to vectorize, and probably don't even require an optimization pass to do so, since the code is pretty explicitly saying *"this data all belongs together and is (probably) going to have the same operations applied to it, so if you have the hardware to do it* **(but as I'll explain below, that's a rather big 'if')** *let's use the SIMD instructions for these types!"*
- Scalar data types are probably not going to be optimized unless you have a really smart compiler. Not every compiler is going to work out *"Well, you have `int`s called `i1`, `i2`, `i3`, `i4`, and they're all having the same operations applied to them, so let's SIMD them!"*.
- Scalar data types within workgroups are almost certainly not going to be vectorized. They'll still be executed concurrently (because if not, then why the hell are we even writing GPGPU code in the first place????) but compilers and runtimes will almost certainly not be able to optimize around them.
- **EDIT**: As pointed out, there are [Compiler Tricks](http://llvm.org/devmtg/2011-11/Rotem_IntelOpenCLSDKVectorizer.pdf) that can make this kind of vectorization possible. But it's worth bearing in mind that these tricks occur at compile-time, not at runtime, which means it's highly dependent on how the code is written, and which compiler (and which optimization flags, if they exist) is used to compile the kernel code.

The big thing to all of this is to bear in mind that all of this depends on the Hardware capabilities of your card. At least among consumer-grade compute cards (translated: GPU's), the hardware engineers are actually not making significant upgrades to their vectorization capabilities, and in fact, are often choosing to cut back on vectorization to focus on making smaller cores which they can then stack more of onto the chip. It's a nice luxury, for example, to have a card with 128 cores, each of which can do 256-bit SIMD instructions, but oftentimes, it's a lot easier to just have a card with tiny cores which don't (or can't) handle SIMD instructions, and simply stack so many cores (like on NVidia's most recent launch, upwards of 4k) that can simply run in parallel, doing the same work (often faster) without depending on the programmer writing explicit SIMD instructions.

I do believe (but don't quote me on this) that both AMD and NVidia guarantee 128-bit vectorization for floats because `float4`-type objects are extremely common in graphics programming, and if you're doing any kind of graphics processing (which is the norm for these kinds of applications) they'll benefit greatly from SIMD operations on those kinds of objects, but anything that's *not* that probably won't see any SIMD optimizations.

Comment: AMD GCN has 16-width SIMD (4 of these per cu) for each wavefront so it should handle float16 at hardware level and maybe have more gain for shifting between vector elements. Newest AMD (vega or somthing) will have both 16,8,4,2,1,1 at hardware level so whatever you give, it will be on hardware (such as having 30 using 16+8+4+2 or 15 using 8+4+2+1)

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik I'll concede to a certain amount of ignorance with respect to AMD's hardware, but IIRC, "Wavefronts" are not single cores, they're groups of cores. So what you're describing is more of an optimization on how Workgroups are submitted and executed. So it's more like what I'm talking about in the second-to-last paragraph on my answer.

Comment: For your 3rd point "Scalar data types across different workgroups are almost certainly not going to be vectorized", did you mean to say across different workitems? I agree that across workgroups there is no way to vectorize, but I read this http://llvm.org/devmtg/2011-11/Rotem_IntelOpenCLSDKVectorizer.pdf and I got the impression that Intel can do vectorization across workitems.

Comment: @Han What's being discussed in that presentation is what I was talking about in my second point, where particularly smart compilers will use tricks to try to coalesce instructions together. Again though: this is something that is done at compile time, not at the time that you define the sizes of the workgroups. And yeah, it's probably more relevant to refer "within" workgroups, rather than across them: I'll update the language.

Comment: @Xirema I assume you are referring compile time as "clBuildProgram", and in your 4th point "this kind of vectorization" means vectorizing adjacent kernel, then my question is how could compiler possibly do that before I define the workgroup size? Like in my question if I say 1 workitem per workgroup, then GPU should not be able to find another workitem to vectorize as I believe communication between workgruops is not allowed. So I'm arguing this has to happen at run-time. (or are you actually referring "this kind of vectorization" to your 2nd point?)

Comment: @Xirema I also read Nvidia's OpenCL manual today, and I think they do this at run-time as SIMT, i.e. at compile time I generate scalar code and at run-time, if the workgroup is large enough, then the adjacent kernels will be vectorized, but not sure is this the same thing as Intel. http://www.nvidia.com/content/cudazone/download/OpenCL/NVIDIA_OpenCL_ProgrammingGuide.pdf